# Stain Matching Wood Trim

Tags: woodworking, staining

I'm having a hard time stain matching some existing interior oak trim. I finally thought I found a good match, but then I realized that the different pieces in the house (even of the same species) look different with the same color stain, so the color that looks good on one piece of oak looks different on another piece of oak. My question is, would I be better off using a gel stain because it doesn't actually soak into the wood and therefore the characteristics of the wood won't matter as much as with penetrating stain? Any other advice?

Comment: Natural wood looks different from piece to piece - only have to look around the interior walls to see lighter and darker patches - it's part of the charm or warmth of the material.

Comment: Install a “pre-stain” before the stain. It will “even out” different growing patterns, make colors more uniform, etc. Test, test, test, before applying to final trim.

Comment: Even pro’s have a hard time getting an exact match on old vs new, you may find it looks ok today and next week it is not close again, part of the joy of remodeling.

Comment: The "pre-stain" @Lee Sam is referencing is often marketed as **Sanding Sealer**.

Comment: yes, gel stain's look is somewhat less dependent on the wood than normal stain. It's not paint, but it is a bit more consistent.